# .NET random SOAP message corruption on large file

Tags: c#, .net, soap

We recently changed our hardware configuration and started getting trouble sending large files over our webservices. On random occasions the soap message we are sending gets corrupt on the receiving end. The message content received differs from the one which was sent. I wrote a little test program which is able to reproduce our problem on a small scale.

The program has a WCF webservice on the receiving end and a windows form application on the sending end. The form application sends a large string to the WCF webservice.
Both communicate using the wshttpbinding. The WCF webservice is installed on IIS7 on a windows server 2008 R2 x64. The windows form application runs on a windows server 2012 standard edition which is virtualized using VMWare (5.0).

Exceptions thrown when trying to read the xml are always like the following (XML corrupt):

```
    System.Xml.XmlException: 'B' is an unexpected token. Expecting white space. Line 1, position 5820605.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributes()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)
   at WCFReciever.Service1.SendXml(String xml) in c:\xxxxxxx\visual studio 2010\Projects\WCFReciever\WCFReciever\Service1.svc.cs:line 22
```

NOTES

- When we run the windows form application on a different server
  (windows server 2008 R2 x64, physical installation), the problem does
  not occur anymore. Since the corruption is random, we are ruling out
  any config, binding, request limit issues.
- basicHttpbinding shows the same problem
- the software has run problem free for 3 years
- The problem occurs for different content ( byte[] +/- 10 MB, string >
  10MB, XML 45 MB , etc)
- We have been debugging this issue for several days now without any result

Thanks in advance!

Code snippets for the test program

Form Application

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Result.Text = string.Empty;

                var client = new WCFReciever.Service1Client();

                //some large file, in this case a xml structured file, 44MB
                var osil = File.ReadAllText("test.osil");

                if (client.SendXml(osil))
                {
                    Result.Text += "success";
                }
                else
                {
                    Result.Text += "failed";
                }                               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Result.Text += ex.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WCF Recvier

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

namespace WCFReciever
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public bool SendXml(string xml)
        {
            try
            {                
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml(xml);                
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {                
                return false;
            }
        }               
    }

    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool SendXml(string xml);
    } 
}
```

Binding Config

```
     <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>          
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpBinding1" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
         openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
         allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
         maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
         messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
         useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFReciever.Service1">
        <endpoint contract="WCFReciever.IService1" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding1"/>
      </service>
      </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. There was an issue between the default installed network adapter by VMWare and server 2012. Using a different network adapter seems to have resolved the problem.